# Invalid use of template name without argument list

Tags: c++, templates

I'm attempting to do two things which are giving me problems:

1) typedef an `std::vector`
2)  declare a `std::auto_ptr`

Both of these are giving me the error `"invalid use of template-name 'std::vector/auto_ptr' without an argument list"`. Here's my headers where the error is being caused:

**ResourceLocationDefinition.h**

```
// ResourceLocationDefinition contains the information needed
// by Ogre to load an external resource.

#ifndef RESOURCELOCATIONDEFINITION_H_
#define RESOURCELOCATIONDEFINITION_H_

#include "string"
#include "vector"

struct ResourceLocationDefinition
{
    ResourceLocationDefinition(std::string type, std::string location, std::string section) :
        type(type),
        location(location),
        section(section)
    {
    }

    ~ResourceLocationDefinition() {}
    std::string type;
    std::string location;
    std::string section;
};

typedef std::vector ResourceLocationDefinitionVector;

#endif
```

**EngineManager.h**

```
#ifndef ENGINEMANAGER_H_
#define ENGINEMANAGER_H_

#include "memory"
#include "string"
#include "map"

#include "OGRE/Ogre.h"
#include "OIS/OIS.h"

#include "ResourceLocationDefinition.h"

// define this to make life a little easier
#define ENGINEMANAGER OgreEngineManager::Instance()

// All OGRE objects are in the Ogre namespace.
using namespace Ogre;

// Manages the OGRE engine.
class OgreEngineManager :
    public WindowEventListener,
    public FrameListener
{
public:
    // Bunch of unrelated stuff to the problem

protected:
    // Constructor. Initialises variables.
    OgreEngineManager();

    // Load resources from config file.
    void SetupResources();

    // Display config dialog box to prompt for graphics options.
    bool Configure();

    // Setup input devices.
    void SetupInputDevices();

    // OGRE Root
    std::auto_ptr root;

    // Default OGRE Camera
    Camera* genericCamera;

    // OGRE RenderWIndow
    RenderWindow* window;

    // Flag indicating if the rendering loop is still running
    bool engineManagerRunning;

    // Resource locations
    ResourceLocationDefinitionVector  resourceLocationDefinitionVector;

    // OIS Input devices
    OIS::InputManager*      mInputManager;
    OIS::Mouse*             mMouse;
    OIS::Keyboard*          mKeyboard;
};

#endif /* ENGINEMANAGER_H_ */
```

Comment: so why not give ita template argument ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using templates, you have to provide template parameters, for your vector, you probably want to do something like this:

```
typedef std::vector<ResourceLocationDefinition> ResourceLocationDefinitionVector;
```

Meaning that your vector references `ResourceLocationDefinition` object instances.

and for your `auto_ptr` something like this:

```
std::auto_ptr<Root> root;
```

I believe you want an `Ogre::Root` pointer there right?

Comment: After doing that, I get a ton of new errors:

http://pastebin.com/bfYuaP9G

I'm on my way to a movie so I'll have to take a closer look later. If it's not something obvious don't spend the time unnecessarily please. I don't want people to have to do my work for me ;)

Comment: They're basically all undefined references. Not sure why giving the templates arguments caused that to happen.

Comment: It seems that you might not be linking with ogre, are you including your the ogre libraries in your project?

Comment: Codeblocks has them linked under my project build options. I didn't have those issues before either. I just built it manually in the terminal and it worked so not sure why codeblocks is ignoring them. Thanks for the help Nick.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear. `auto_ptr` and `vector` are templates. They require you to specify the type that you actually want to use with them.

```
struct my_type {
  int x, y;
}; 
std::vector<my_type> v; // a vector of my_type
std::vector<int> iv; // a vector of integers
```

Concerning `auto_ptr`: It has been deprecated because of its weird semantics. Consider using a `std::unique_ptr` (when available on your platform) or `boost::scoped_ptr` (when you have a boost dependency.)

Comment: GCC supports C++11.  I'll look at the documentation when I get home, thanks for the tip.